# Finding probability using binomial distribution.

Tags: probability, binomial-distribution

I am given a question that there is a quiz consisting of 20 true or false questions. Probability of answering correctly is 0.95. What is the probability that a given student answers all questions correctly?
Now what I did is that I took it as a Binomial Distribution. Here $n=20$ and also $k=20$. Is my selection of $n$ and $k$ right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that should work. Note that it may be simpler to just note that the questions are independent, so the probability of getting them all correct is just $(0.95)^{20}$ (you get the same answer both ways).